# Камера от третьего лица OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Во время изучения OpenGL я захотел сделать гонку. Как сделать камеру от первого лица я понял, а вот как сделать камеру от третьего лица? Я попробовал за позицию камеры принимать углы поворота камеры. Понимаю, что глупая идея, но что-то получилось, камера почти нормально перемещается, но не до конца, тем более она улетает всё дальше и дальше от машины.
main.cpp

```
 #define NOMINMAX

#include <windows.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
using namespace sf;

float angleX, angleY; // Углы поворота камеры


#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
//класс модели
class Model {
public:
    float* vertexArray;
    float* normalArray;
    float* uvArray;
    int numVerts;
    GLuint ModelTexture;

    void Load(string filename, string texture) {
        ModelTexture = LoadTexture(texture);
        Assimp::Importer importer;
        const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(filename, aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Fast);//aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Fast has the configs you'll need

        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[0]; //assuming you only want the first mesh
        numVerts = mesh->mNumFaces * 3;

        vertexArray = new float[mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 3];
        normalArray = new float[mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 3];
        uvArray = new float[mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 2];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
        {
            const aiFace& face = mesh->mFaces[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                aiVector3D uv = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][face.mIndices[j]];
                memcpy(uvArray, &uv, sizeof(float) * 2);
                uvArray += 2;

                aiVector3D normal = mesh->mNormals[face.mIndices[j]];
                memcpy(normalArray, &normal, sizeof(float) * 3);
                normalArray += 3;

                aiVector3D pos = mesh->mVertices[face.mIndices[j]];
                memcpy(vertexArray, &pos, sizeof(float) * 3);
                vertexArray += 3;
            }
        }

        uvArray -= mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 2;
        normalArray -= mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 3;
        vertexArray -= mesh->mNumFaces * 3 * 3;
    }
    void Draw() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ModelTexture);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexArray);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normalArray);

        //glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvArray);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVerts);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
};
//класс игрока
class Player : public Model
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    float dx, dy, dz;
    float maxspeed, speed = 0, angle = 0;
    float acc = 0.02, dec = 0.1;
    float turnSpeed = 0.08;
    bool Up = 0, Right = 0, Down = 0, Left = 0;
    Player(float x0, float y0, float z0, float maxspeed)
    {
        x = x0;
        y = y0;
        z = z0;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        dz = 0;
        this->maxspeed = maxspeed;
    }

    void update(float time)
    {
        if (Up && speed < maxspeed)
            if (speed < 0)  speed += dec;
            else  speed += acc;

        if (Down && speed > -maxspeed)
            if (speed > 0) speed -= dec + 0.02;
            else  speed -= acc - 0.01;

        if (!Up && !Down)
            if (speed - dec > 0) speed -= 0.01;
            else if (speed + dec < 0) speed += 0.01;
            else speed = 0;

        if (Right && speed != 0) {
            angle += turnSpeed * time / speed + 0.005f;
        }
        if (Left && speed != 0) {
            angle -= turnSpeed * time / speed + 0.005f;
        }
        x += sin(angle) * speed * time;
        z -= cos(angle) * speed * time;
        Up = 0;
        Down = 0;
        Right = 0;
        Left = 0;
    }

    void keyboard()
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            Up = 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
        {
            Down = 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            Right = 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            Left = 1;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    //инициализируем glew
    glewInit();
    //настройки для окна SFML
    ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits = 24;
    Window window(VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL", Style::Default, settings);

    //настройки для OpenGL
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.f, 800.f / 600.f, 0.1, 50000.f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    float pos[] = { 10, 10, 10, 1 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
    float dif[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, dif);
    float amb[] = { 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, amb);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    ShowCursor(GL_FALSE);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //текстура неба
    GLuint skybox[6];
    skybox[0] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_front.bmp");
    skybox[1] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_back.bmp");
    skybox[2] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_left.bmp");
    skybox[3] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_right.bmp");
    skybox[4] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_bottom.bmp");
    skybox[5] = LoadTexture("resources/skybox/skybox_top.bmp");
    //////////////////////////
    Clock clock;
    Player p(105, 3, -100, 100);
    Model map;
    //загружаем модели
    p.Load("normal.obj", "0000.bmp");
    map.Load("track.obj", "texture.png");
    //float angle = 0, posX = 0, posY = 0, posZ = 0;
    float camX = p.x, camY = p.y, camZ = p.z;
    //////основной цикл/////////
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        //время
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
        clock.restart();
        time = time / 50;
        if (time > 3) time = 3;

        //обработка событий
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape))
                window.close();

        }

        //чистим всё
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        p.keyboard();
        p.update(time);

        //мышь
        POINT mousexy;
        GetCursorPos(&mousexy);
        int xt = window.getPosition().x + 400;
        int yt = window.getPosition().y + 300;

        angleX += (xt - mousexy.x) / 4; //4 — чувствительность
        angleY += (yt - mousexy.y) / 4;

        SetCursorPos(xt, yt);
        //////////////////
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //камера
        camX = p.x;
        camY = p.y + 5;
        camZ = p.z + 30;

        camX += angleX;
        camY += -angleY;
        camZ += -angleX;

        gluLookAt(camX, camY, camZ, p.x, p.y, p.z, 0, 1, 0);

        //рисуем небо
        glTranslatef(p.x, p.y, p.z);
        RenderSkybox(skybox, 10000);
        glTranslatef(-p.x, -p.y, -p.z);
        //рисуем модель
        glTranslatef(p.x, p.y, p.z);
        glRotated(-p.angle * 180 / PI, 0, 1, 0);
        p.Draw();
        glRotated(p.angle * 180 / PI, 0, 1, 0);
        glTranslatef(-p.x, -p.y, -p.z);
        //рисуем карту
        map.Draw();

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define NDEBUG
#define GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE 0x812F
using namespace std;
const float PI = 3.141592653;

void RenderSkybox(GLuint skybox[], float size)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //front
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //back
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //left
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //right
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //bottom
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //top       
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
    glEnd();
}

void RenderShape(GLuint texture, float x, float y, float z) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-x, -y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(x, -y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(x, y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-x, y, -z);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-x, y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(x, y, z);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); glVertex3f(-x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-x, -y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-x, y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-x, y, z);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x, -y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(x, y, -z);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(x, -y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(x, -y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-x, -y, -z);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-x, y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(x, y, -z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-x, y, z);

    glEnd();
}

GLuint LoadTexture(sf::String name)
{
    sf::Image image;
    if (!image.loadFromFile(name))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    image.flipVertically();

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону `gluLookAt` - это то что вам нужно. Т.е. конструирование матрицы вида по положению камеры и положению "цели".

Камера должна быть объектом вашего мира, со своим положением, углом поворота и тп. Тогда вы сможете относительно просто задавать правила, что камера должна висеть позади машины на таком-то расстоянии под таким-то углом и следить за направление езды с некоторой задержкой, как сделано во всех обычных гонках.

Comment: То есть мне нужно написать класс камеры?

Comment: Это уже вам виднее, писать класс или просто метод с параметрами. У меня, например, это класс, т.к. у камеры много свойств и ей нужно много методов (тот же фрустум, к примеру)

Comment: Я тоже выберу класс, но как реализовать вращение камеры вокруг машины? Я вот это не понимаю.